# Group mysql results by "every 30 days"

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(id) as amount,
  DATEDIFF(expire, buydate) as days
FROM `vw8mv_orders`
GROUP BY MONTH(expire)
```

The result is:

```
    amount  days
    1       22
    1       30
    1       105
    1       161
```

I'd like to see these results in a group (every 30 days). If days value is between 1 and 30 days, then put this in 30days group, if bet 31-60, put to 60days group, etc.

For example:

```
    amount  time
      2     30 days
      0     60 days
      1     90 days
```

Comment: i guess  in your expected result set 60 days group should have amount 0 by match the output of your query ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create a calculated column to group by. There are several approaches you could use for the calculation, but a good option might be integer division using the [DIV operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as amount,
    (((datediff(expire, buydate) DIV 30) + 1) * 30) as timegroup
FROM
    table
GROUP BY timegroup;
```

The reason I like this approach, rather than using for example [some fancy arithmetic with `ROUND()`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,84300,84326#msg-84326), is that it's a little more clear what you're trying to do. `datediff(expire, buydate) DIV 30` says, take the difference of these dates, and tell me "how many 30s" are in that number.

That's all you need for your grouping; the rest is there to make the column display the way you want it, as `30, 60, 90, ...` instead of as `0, 1, 2, ...`.

Another option, if you're not comfortable with integer division, would be the [`CEILING` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as amount,
    30 * CEILING(datediff(expire, buydate) / 30) as timegroup
FROM
    table
GROUP BY timegroup;
```

Mathematically speaking, `CEILING(x / N)` is equivalent to `((x DIV N) + 1)`, but it's a little less busy with `CEILING()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a subselect over the result returned from your query,below is the example query

```
SELECT COUNT(`amount`) as amount,
 CONCAT(ROUND(`days` / 30) * 30, ' Days')
 as `time`
 FROM `t`
 GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY ROUND(`days` / 30)
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cafdb/12)

For your query you can do so

```
SELECT COUNT(`amount`) as amount,
 CONCAT(ROUND(`days` / 30) * 30, ' Days')
 as `time`
FROM(
SELECT COUNT(id) as amount,
 datediff(expire, buydate) as days 
FROM `vw8mv_orders` 
GROUP BY MONTH(expire)
) t
 GROUP BY `time`
ORDER BY ROUND(`days` / 30)
```